# How to refresh with ajax in php?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, function

I'm trying to make a likes/claps/heart system on my site and found this site (https://www.techolac.com/wordpress/how-to-add-likes-to-posts-in-wordpress-without-a-plugin/) that taught how to do it. I made some adjustments the problem is that when I do like the page refresh and I just wanted the number to refresh and not the whole page.
I saw what I could do in AJAX but i didnt know how.

Functions.php / Wordpress

```
// Add buttons to top of post content
function ip_post_likes($content) {
    ob_start();
    ?>
    <a href="<?php echo add_query_arg('post_action', 'like'); ?>">
        <span class="icon-claps pr-2"><?php echo get_like_count('likes') ?></span>
    </a>
    <?php
    $output = ob_get_clean();
    return $output . $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'ip_post_likes');

//Get like
function get_like_count($type = 'likes') {
    $current_count = get_post_meta(get_the_id(), $type, true);
    return ($current_count ? $current_count : '');
}
//Process like
function ip_process_like() {
    $processed_like = false;
    $redirect       = false;
    // Check if like
    if(is_singular('post')) {
        if(isset($_GET['post_action'])) {
            if($_GET['post_action'] == 'like') {
                // Like
                $like_count = get_post_meta(get_the_id(), 'likes', true);
                if($like_count) {
                    $like_count = $like_count + 1;
                }else {
                    $like_count = 0;
                }
                $processed_like = update_post_meta(get_the_id(), 'likes', $like_count);
            }
            if($processed_like) {
                $redirect = get_the_permalink();
            }
        }
    }
    // Redirect
    if($redirect) {
        wp_redirect($redirect);
        die;
    }
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'ip_process_like');
```

The problem is that when I do like the page refresh and I just wanted the number to refresh and not the whole page.
I saw what I could do in AJAX but i didnt know how.

Comment: you need to add the ajax code in front end and call the method you wrote in php. You can use this: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ Then you can update the page element when you receive the answer to the ajax in the response block. Edit: can you show what you tried in front end?

Comment: _"I saw what I could do in AJAX but i didnt know how"_ - That's when you should start by doing a lot of research and make some attempts. You can start by reading [this blog post](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/using-ajax-with-wordpress/) that goes through how you can use ajax in Wordpress. If you google for "wordpress ajax", you will find even more guides and tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

Image:

[This is the whole code. I am using wordpres and twig / timber](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTyuw.png)